# Delete last line from multiple CSV files within a directory

Tags: python, csv, file

I am trying to delete the very last line of multiple `CSV` files within a directory, **overwriting** the original file.

Input file example:

```
^AEX,14/04/2021,708.83,713.31,708.44,712.55,70200
^AEX,15/04/2021,713.21,714.98,712.37,713.8,71100
^AEX,16/04/2021,714.48,716.8,712.57,716.8,80786700
^AEX,19/04/2021,717.05,718.5,710.62,711.94,60100
^AEX,20/04/2021,717.05,718.5,710.62,711.94,60100
```

Output file example: (with the last line `^AEX,20/04/2021` deleted)

```
^AEX,14/04/2021,708.83,713.31,708.44,712.55,70200
^AEX,15/04/2021,713.21,714.98,712.37,713.8,71100
^AEX,16/04/2021,714.48,716.8,712.57,716.8,80786700
^AEX,19/04/2021,717.05,718.5,710.62,711.94,60100
```

I wrote the following code but it is not working:

```py
import csv
import operator
import glob

path="./Original/*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)

for filename in files:
    lines = open(file).readlines()
    lines = lines[:-1]

    # deletes content of the file
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)

    # writes the new data to the file
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(lists)
```

Comment: You are not saving the file descriptor in `f` since you are opening and reading the files in one pass. Also, consider using the `with` statement and replacing `glob` with `pathlib` perhaps.

Comment: Does it have to be Python? This is trivial with `sed`: `sed -i '$d' foo.csv`

Comment: As suggested by @JanChristophTerasa, perhaps `head -n-1` is an easier option.

Comment: @accdias That's another way of doing it, yes. Though `head` does not have the built-in _in-place_ option.

Comment: @accdias: because I was not able to reply the code here as a comment, I did it as an answer below (sorry, I am really a newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
from glob import glob

csv_files = glob('./Original/*.csv')

for csv_file in csv_files:
    with open(csv_file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[:-1]

    with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: My pleasure, @Joao.